# if else statement not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with `if (stat2 == stat)` statement. The remove class is not fired 
despite in console I can see that stat2 and  stat  has the same value.

Solved, I've had to assign new value to stat2 after changing it

```
$('.minus').on('click', function(e){
    var ap = $('.add-points').data('ap');
    var stat = $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').data('stat');
    var ap2 = $('.add-points').data('ap2');
    var stat2 = $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').data('stat2');
    var newamount = ap2 + 1;
    var newstat = stat2 - 1;
    if (ap2 == ap || stat2 == stat ) {
        alert("nie mozesz wiecej odjac");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').val(newstat);
        $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').data('stat2', newstat);
        var stat2 = $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').data('stat2');
        if (stat2 == stat) {
            $(this).closest('.stat').find('.number-field').removeClass('updated');
        } else {
        }
        $('.unassigned').html(newamount);
        $('.add-points').data('ap2', newamount);

    }     
});
```

Comment: Floating point equality comparisons? Dangerous.

Comment: Try using === rather than ==.

Comment: try: stat.toFixed(2)==stat2.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to assign new value to stat2 after changing it to newstat

corrected the code in question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got the same .number-field element?
In your function we can see the .number-field you got is the closet one to your event target(.minus).
But when you test, we don't know which .number-field element you got.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of the current scenario :

```
if stat == stat2
    alert
else
    if stat == stat2
        remove class
```

Obviously, `stat` must be different than `stat2` in order to reach the `else` block, but in this case the class is not removed.